# Solana RPC Websocket Proxy Setup

Tags: rpc, websocket, proxy

I am working on solana node. I have two node running on big servers. I made some endpoints on my rpc node using express node JS. But i am facing an issue of web socket connectivity. Is there any way to resolve web socket issue. My express app only contains db connections and routes configurations so we can use our rpc node using or own routes.
So i am looking in a way to solve web socket issue.